# Using own exceptions in wse, not only SoapException

Tags: c#, .net, wse

Is it possible to send my own developed exceptions over Soap to a client using http.sys??

Comment: WSE is obsolete. All new web service work should be done using WCF, and existing WSE code should be migrated or retired ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge unfortunately the answer is no. You cannot build your own custom exceptions on the server side and expect to use them on the client side through WSE. I can't give much technical background as to why (as in why this is not allowed by WSE), but I am sure about my answer because I tested this out.

You can use the approach described in the provided link to return a custom exception that inherits from a System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException, however you must capture the exception on the client side as a SoapException since you will not be able to capture it as the custom exception type: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229064.aspx

To recreate the test for your own confirmation do the following:

1. Create a test exception class, call it whatever you'd like and make sure it follows the pattern described in the link I provided above (there are code samples provided).
2. Create a web method that explicitly returns the test exception like so:

   ```
   'This is in VB.Net
   <WebMethod()> _
   Public Function ThrowTestSoapException() As TestSoapException
       Return New TestSoapException()
   End Function
   ```
3. Try to regenerate your client's WSE Library (using WseWsdl3.exe) and you should receive an error message like this one: "*Error: Server unavailable, please try later*"

That is as far as I could get when trying to create my own transferable Custom Exceptions. Again the only thing I was able to do was return a Custom Exception that inherited from the SoapException class, and caught it on the client side as a SoapException. That is the same method described in the link that "CheGueVerra" pointed out [above](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480592.aspx).

In response to John Saunders's comment above: Yes, if *possible* move over to WCF, WSE is indeed obsolete. Since this is work related for me and for others asking these questions, making a shift from WSE to WCF would require managerial approval - so some of us cannot make those changes easily - even if we desperately want to.

Comment: It is, of course, our job to properly inform management, so they can make the right decision.

Comment: And after informing management that we are falling behind in technology they look at us and say "No it will take too long, which means it will be too expensive to do (man hours), stop complaining and keep up with tickets" then what do you suggest? You think I haven't tried? I have written proposals that just get tossed aside. So again - stop and think about what you are suggesting - of course people want to use the latest and greatest, but when your management is brain dead there isn't much hope of it actually happening anytime soon. So congrats your message is clear "use WCF" - IF possible.

Comment: I have always said "if possible". And I agree. Once you've told you management that their "important" code is based on obsolete and nearly-unsupported software, there's not much more to be done, other than continuing to keep a good eye on the job market.

Comment: I hear you. I already changed jobs for that exact reason. I was tired of working on ASP, ASP.Net v1.1 Web Services, 1.1 Remoting and a bunch of other really old technologies that I fought to upgrade, but I was told it was "too risky" and would "take too much time". I left that place, but this new place uses WSE still so I am fighting the same battle here the only difference is they are open to change. Until then I will be working with WSE, I already implemented WCF in some other places here and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can throw your own exceptions. Any uncaught exception that does not derive from SoapException will be bottled up by the .NET framework into a SoapException. You can derive from SoapException if you want to control how certain parts of the SoapException are formed (for instance, the fault and detail portions).

Answer (score 0):

Like the ASMX services it is based on, WSE has little support for SOAP Faults. You can return them (SoapException with Detail property set), but they won't appear in the WSDL. If received by a WSE client, they will appear as SoapException, not as a custom exception type.

WCF does have full support for SOAP faults, both on the client and the server side.